# How to change O365 Tenant Display Name or Organization Name using Powershell

Tags: office365

I've been finding Powershell commands to change Office 365 Tenant Display name or Organization Name but unable to find any. The reason why I need it through Powershell is because I have 500 advisors and each advisor has it's own Office 365 tenant account. Login to each tenant one by one and changing names will take much of my time, so I need help if Powershell can do this for me as quickly as possible.
Any help is much appreciated.

[Organization Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxPuD.jpg)

[Tenant Name under Properites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lao8B.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should read the official [Azure Active Directory V2 PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0) documentation. There are

- [`Get-AzureADTenantDetail`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Azuread/Get-AzureADTenantDetail?view=azureadps-2.0) for listing the details and
- [`Set-AzureADTenantDetail`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Azuread/Set-AzureADTenantDetail?view=azureadps-2.0) for setting contact information.

Because `Get-AzureADTenantDetail` can list the
`DisplayName` but `Set-AzureADTenantDetail` can only change the contact information (`-MarketingNotificationEmails`, `-SecurityComplianceNotificationMails`, `-SecurityComplianceNotificationPhones` & `-TechnicalNotificationMails`) this strongly suggests **there's no PowerShell command for changing the display name**.

Comment: Thank you Esa Jokinen, I in fact checked these two Commands and found them not useful in my case, so thought to ask a question here if any Office 365 Powershell expert can suggest another command if any.

Comment: I'd like to be wrong this time. :)